# Page Break does not work

Tags: css, google-maps

Im struggling with printing a map from Google maps API on an entire page, but the image just gets cut and separate in two different pages.

I have tried the page break attribute but it still dividing the printing.

This is my css

```
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}
@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    page-break-after: avoid;    
  }
  .go_btn{
display:none;
}

@page {
    margin: 0;

}

}
```

This is the test I been trying with.
Any ideas what could be wrong?

[Demo](http://ge.nu/maps/test.php)

Comment: Have you tried applying the page break attribute only to `page[size="A4"]` and not to `body`?

Comment: @sideroxylon Hey.
Yes tried that to, same margin problem :(

Comment: Oh well..only other suggestion is change `page-break-after: avoid` to `page-break-inside: avoid` and maybe add `page-break-after: always` to try to force the page break to after your block level element (`page`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these attributes and it will work flawlessly. The height limits it to one page, and the display forces it to fill the whole page.

```
display:inline-block;
height: 100%;
```

Example in your css:

```
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}
@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;  
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    page-break-after: avoid;    
  }
  .go_btn{
display:none;
}

@page {
margin: 0;

}

}
```